# Why can't I see cookie value in a WebSocket handshake request header?

Tags: javascript, cookies, websocket

I wanted to send a websocket handshake request from an html page and wrote codes like below:

```
  document.cookie = "guestId=xxxx; remember=xxxxxx;";
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/ws");
```

But what shown in Chrome Dev Tools appears that no cookie was sent:

```
General:
  Request URL:ws://localhost:5000/ws
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:307 Temporary Redirect
Response Headers
  Content-Length:59
  Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
  Date:Fri, 18 Mar 2016 09:39:11 GMT
  Location:/preorder/landing/index
Request Headers
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:Upgrade
  Host:localhost:5000
  Origin:http://localhost:63342
  Pragma:no-cache
  Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
  Sec-WebSocket-Key:t3N0vVaLCsOmOXLSh+Arsw==
  Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
  Upgrade:websocket
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
```

How can I fix this? Why there is no cookie in request headers? If I send other ajax request not upgraded, I can see cookies in Dev Tools. Why is there such differences?

Answer (score 2):

Your **Origin** header is **http://localhost:63342** and the WS request is to **ws://localhost:5000/ws** so your domains are different (different ports). I imagine your other ajax requests are to **http://localhost:63342** and thus the browser sends the cookie.

Comment: Different ports does not change a cookie's domain; cookies are explicitly shared across ports on the same domain.

Comment: @Jez Well, you would generally be considered correct on that I'd say; it is generally accepted kinda incorrectly correct behaviour (meaning cookies should have been CORS segregated, but weren't, and it then stuck to retain backwards compatibility) but the history of actual browser behaviour is spotty, some versions of some browsers definitely segregated cookies by TCP port... you'd hope these days it wouldn't happen, but the OP posted 7 years ago, so not sure... you can go and research or test that specific version of Chrome on that OS if you like but that sounds hard work to me :D

Comment: @Jez There are definitely other possibilities though, some could obviously be eliminated by various research, or trying things, but for my part I think a suggested answer is a reasonable place to stop, I don't work for the OP after all :D If it was definitive that you were correct on this point and thus I had to move on to the next possibility I can think of, I'd wonder if setting `document.cookie` was ineffective because of the way the websocket lib works, it may be necessary to sent the cookie header explicitly wit the websocket request. Perhaps I should have posted 2 answers :D

Comment: It seems to be standardized in [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), so browsers distinguishing by port aren't following that.  I'd add that as a web developer I find it handy for them not to distinguish by port, as when I'm developing on localhost I may be running multiple processes on multiple ports which need cookies shared, as they're the equivalent of sharing between a domain and its subdomains on a production system.

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
ws.on("headers", function(headers) {
    headers["set-cookie"] = "yokokkie";
});
```

Comment: This would not work. There are only 4 message types: close, error, message, and open. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#events